# Scroll snap to effect on divs with 100% height

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm looking to add a scroll effect, snapping to the top of a div when the scroll wheel is released. The only problem is each div has 100% height (thus one image will be on screen at a time).
I come across this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djsbaker/dxzk4/ which seems to work nicely with 300px intervals, but how can something like this be translated to divs with 100% height?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="fill-browser" style="background-image: url(../images/background-v2.jpg)"></div>
<div class="fill-browser" style="background-image: url(../images/background-v2.jpg)"></div>
<div class="fill-browser" style="background-image: url(../images/background-v2.jpg)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .fill-browser{
    position:relative;
    left: 1%;
    height:98%;
    width:98%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
            }
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo too: http://jsfiddle.net/vHAWW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with 100% too,

depending on how many boxes you have yu need to set the boxes parent height to boxes * 100 and the boxes heights to 100/boxes, also dont forget to make the body and html 100% too.

jsfiddle.net/WQtA8

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
.box
{
    color: #fff;
    height: 10%;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
#container {
    height:1000%;
    width:300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.red {background-color:red;}
.green {background-color:green;}
.yellow {background-color:yellow;}
```

edit:

since you are using jquery allready, might as well calculate and set the heights dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var boxes = $(".box").length;
var height = boxes * 100 + "%";
var boxheight = 100/boxes + "%";
$("#container").css({ height : height });
  $(".box").css({height: boxheight});
});
```

Comment: will this code work on my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vHAWW/ can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: it will work with any fiddle. dont you notice the difference in js in those fiddles? take the working and apply it to your own :) Pro tip: Make sure classes and element referrences in the juery match your htmls!

Comment: yes, of course, and thank you by the way :) but that fiddle you posted, while the divs may now be 100% in height, they are still snapping every 300px?

Comment: ah yes i see it now. your problem seems to be this line in the js     var individualDivHeight = 300;
the js needs to be edited somehow so its not 300px hardcoded

Comment: try this, seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/WQtA8/ edited the line to read the actual div height, instead being set to 300

Comment: yes, and that's the bit I couldn't figure out as to how it will be every 100% instead of 300px?

Comment: see the new fiddle in my last comment, fixed that line

Comment: just seen that, works perfectly! Maybe it's just me being stupid but I can't seem to get it to work in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vHAWW/ it just doesn't seem to let you scroll?

Comment: there is no autoscroll effect. compare the 2 fiddles and notice the missing js in yours. yours only has js to set height, no animation no scrollto() and so on...

Comment: sorry, thought i'd updated it, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vHAWW/1/

Comment: not sure. maybe some css maybe the additional js you have there. you have a demo working however so try building on it or see what difference causes the problem